# Visualisation with kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega-lite

I want to visualize the the distribution of durations. On the x axis i want 1-x ms and on the y axis how many of the data fit to that. The duration is in a field i made in elastic search, but i cant access it.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "title": "Duration counts from all indexes",
  "data": {
    "url": {
      "index": "_all",
      "body": {
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {"exists": {"field": "duration"}},
              {"query_string": {"query": "duration:*"}}
            ]
          }
        },
        "aggs": {
          "duration_counts": {
            "histogram": {
              "field": "duration",
              "interval": 1 // Use appropriate interval based on your data
            }
          }
        },
        "size": 0
      }
    },
    "format": {"property": "aggregations.duration_counts.buckets"}
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "key", "type": "quantitative", "axis": {"title": "Duration"}},
    "y": {"field": "doc_count", "type": "quantitative", "axis": {"title": "Document count"}}
  }
}
```

and the error message is: Infinite extent for field "key": [Infinity, -Infinity] and Infinite extent for field "doc_count": [Infinity, -Infinity]
How can i fix this?

Dont know what to do

Answer (score 0):

try to test with `date_histogram` rather than a `histogram`.

```
      "duration_counts": {
        "histogram": {
          "field": "duration",
          "interval": 1 // Use appropriate interval based on your data
        }
      }
    }
```

---

```
      "duration_counts": {
        "date_histogram": {
          "field": "duration",
          "calendar_interval": "month" 
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Now it tells me that the Interval format is Invalid

Comment: please check the official documentation.  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html

Comment: did you update the interval to calendar_interval?